# where meta tag works?

Tags: html, jdeveloper

i have a html page with tag:`<meta charset="utf-8">` when i click on it to display in browser and use

arabic language for links it works fine.

but when i put it inside jdeveloper application folder and display it the arabic language won't work unless i change it with tag:`<meta charset="windows-1256">`.

so i want to knew why?

> > is meta tag works on server side or what?

Answer (score 1):

It is not only the charset of your HTML, it is also the charset of the data you want to type with jdeveloper. Try to convert it to UTF-8 before displaying it and keep the meta to UTF-8.

I hope it helps!

Comment: i try it with utf-8 in jdeveloper but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler setting in your JDeveloper project properties - specifically the character encoding.